# Tour mit einem geschulten Touristenführer erleben/durchlaufen?

Tags: single-word-request, phrase

Folgendes Problem.

Eine Stadt bietet Stadtrundgänge an. Diese Rundgänge kann man *kostenlos* von der Webseite herunterladen und selbst mit einer Karte durchlaufen.

Nun muss ein Hinweis angebracht werden, dass diese Tour auch mit einem Fremdenführer, Touristenführer **kostenpflichtig** durchgelaufen werden kann.

Wie formuliert man das nun richtig und verständlich **in einem Satz.** Nach diesem Satz kommt die Auflistung mit Preisen.

Mein Versuch:

> Diese Tour kann auch mit einem geschulten Touristenführer erlebt
>   werden

Dies ist allerdings nicht so gut, da es nicht gleich klar ist, dass man solche Führungen **buchen muss**. Außerdem passt das Wort *erleben* auch nicht so gut.

Comment: Du hast doch schon eine gute Alternative genannt: eine Führung / einen Touristenführer buchen. Wieso nicht also einfach: "Für diese Tour können Sie auch einen geschulten Fremdenführer buchen." oder "Als Begleitung für diese Tour stehen auch unsere geschulten Fremdenführer bereit, die Sie bei ... buchen können".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Sie können für diese Tour auch einen geschulten Stadtführer buchen.

Ich würde den Satz ein bisschen umstellen, denn wenn *Sie* das Subjekt ist, kann *buchen* ohne Probleme verwendet werden. Kleinere Modifikationen sind selbstverständlich noch möglich.

Alternativ, wenn die *Tour* das erste Satzglied bleiben soll:

> Für diese Tour können Sie auch einen geschulten Stadtführer buchen.

(Ich finde, *Touristenführer* klingt ein wenig seltsam, und würde auf *Stadtführer* ausweichen.)

Comment: Touristenführer finde ich auch seltsam. Wiki schlägt `Fremdenführer` vor. Wäre das nicht besser?

Comment: @dit *Fremdenführer* gefällt mir auch.

Answer (score 3):

Mein Vorschlag wäre:

> Diese Tour ist auf Anfrage auch mit einem geschulten Touristenführer verfügbar.

oder:

> Diese Tour ist auf Anfrage auch mit einem geschulten Touristenführer *buchbar*.

Comment: Der erste Satz klingt besser, drückt aber nicht aus, dass dies kostenpflichtig ist. Der zweite suggeriert zwar entstehende Kosten, klingt aber nicht mehr so schön. Dilemma.

Comment: Nach dem Satz soll ja eine Auflistung der Preise folgen. Deshalb dachte ich mir, dass man nicht unbedingt auf entstehende Kosten eingehen muss.